# Columnwise Matrix Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Do you know what is "Columnwise Matrix Multiplication"? I searched for it but couldn't find any explanation about the algorithm or a pseudo code.

It would be great if somebody explains that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but matrix multiplication can be implemented more cache-friendly by having one factor stored row-wise and one factor column wise, such that the sums for individual entries of the result can be calculated with fewer cache misses. Perhaps this is meant?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
http://www.wi1.uni-muenster.de/pi/lehre/ws0910/pppa/papers/mvm.pdf